# How to get a .exe packaged Ruby Shoes app to reference resources outside the package?

Tags: ruby, windows, shoes

I'm trying to make a standalone .exe packaged Ruby Shoes app that uses images dynamically, meaning whichever images is found in the folder of the .exe file.

```
Shoes.app() {
  background "bg.jpg"
}
```

This code works if the image is in the same folder when the .exe is packaged, and the image seems to be packaged into the .exe since it's not needed in the same folder as the .exe for it to display when running the exe. But when you want it to load the file in the same folder as the .exe, packaging the app without the image, it does not show. I've tried different ways at finding absolute path to the current directory where the .exe is launched from, but they all seem to point to some temporary directory under AppData and not where the .exe file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Calling **pwd** should get you what you want
Nope, Ok sorry get it now !:-)
Shoes is opening your exe/shy into AppData/temp so working directory and **__FILE__** both point there !
Someone, some time ago proposed this : [Trying to access the "current dir" in a packaged Shoes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475988/trying-to-access-the-current-dir-in-a-packaged-shoes-app?rq=1)

must be a better way !

**EDIT**:
you probably want custom packager (check **"i want advanced install options"**)
check **"Expand shy in users directory"**
Do as you done for regular packaging.
Now when launching the exe, it will ask you( or the user) to choose where to install your app, proceed, note the directory.
Now before launching the installed app feed the noted directory with your resources and you should be ok

Some references : https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3/wiki/Custom-Install-Scripts
(there's a lot more to it)
https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3/issues/247#issuecomment-213919829

Comment: I noticed that post, but sadly the workarounds suggested there is not really viable for my project.

Comment: When trying what you wrote in your edit I get stuck like this: http://i.imgur.com/CztIXRm.png

Windows Repack, it says and it never gives me a .exe file.

Comment: @MaloW, did you choose an installer icon ? i'm stuck too if i don't select one.

Comment: After adding an installer icon it packages, but when trying to run the .exe file I'm getting this error: http://i.imgur.com/mJUMHUY.png

Answer (score 0):

Edit: my first answer was incomplete. Windows is a little odd in Shoes for packaged apps. Write a little test script.

```
Shoes.app do
  stack do
    para "DIR: #{DIR}"
    para "LIB_DIR: #{LIB_DIR}"
    cdir = Dir.getwd
    para "CWD: #{cdir}"
  end
end
```

Dir.getwd is probably what you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but Dir.getwd still returns C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/Temp/shoes-min.4268 when running from a .shy or .exe file. LIB_DIR returns C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/Shoes, and DIR returns C:/Program Files (x86)/Shoes